# Java enums, static class variables - why can't I do this?

Tags: java, enums

I am getting a "cannot be resolved" error when I try to do this:

```
class Tag{
   public static final int blah = 1231; 
}

enum Things{
    COOL (Tag.blah, "blah"); //error here
}
```

the compiler complains that it cannot find the Tag class on the line above.

Comment: Having added an appropriate constructor to Things (to take an int and a string) it compiles fine for me... it's probably something in your environment, and you haven't said anything about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well turns out the error was just stupidity on my part.

I was referring to a member variable, (**blah** in above example) that did not exist! So it wasn't resolving **Tag.blah**!

Answer (score 3):

Visibility is probably the error here. Your class Tag has default visibility, so I guess your enum is not in the same package. Use `public class Tag`

EDIT:

this compiles from inside a common outer class:

```
class Tag {
    public static final int blah = 1231;
}

enum Things {
    COOL(Tag.blah, "blah"); // error here

    private Things(final int i, final String s) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following complete `EnumTest.java` file compile. I'm not sure what your problem is; there isn't enough information.

```
public class EnumTest {
    class Boo {
        static final int x = 42;
    }
    enum Things {
        X(Boo.x);
        Things(int x) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: @drozzy: if it's visible, it's fine. There's nothing special about `enum` and `static` class variables. Try `import static Tag.blah;` and see if you can even see `Tag` from `Things`.

Comment: Sorry mistake on my part... see update. Not sure what to do with the question... can't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined the constructor of the COOL enum?  You are passing it parameters, but the default constructor does not accept any.